# Getting ArrayIndexBounds Exception in BaseAdapter

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I am creating an application in which it consist of a listview instead that listview it contains expandable listview when i select an item in the expandable list view i am getting an error as follows:

```
E/JavaBinder: *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
                                        java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=5
```

Adapter:

```
public class Daybooklist_adapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ArrayList<Daybooklist> daybooklists;
DatabaseHandler databaseHandler;
boolean isListScrolling;
public Daybooklist_adapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Daybooklist> daybooklists) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.daybooklists = daybooklists;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return daybooklists.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return daybooklists.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertview == null)
        convertview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.model_daybook_listentry, null);
    final TextView day_name = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.tv_daybook_name);
    final TextView day_description = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.tv_daybook_description);
    final TextView day_type = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.tv_daybook_type);
    final TextView day_amount = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.tv_daybook_amount);
    final TextView day_usertype = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.tv_usertype);
    final TextView day_time = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.tv_daybook_time);
    final ImageView day_check = (ImageView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.img_doneall);
    final TextView daybook_location = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.tv_daybook_location);
    databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(activity);
    // getting movie data for the row

    final Daybooklist m = daybooklists.get(position);
    if (m.getUsertype() != null && !m.getUsertype().isEmpty()) {
        if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("farmer") | m.getUsertype().startsWith("singleworker") | m.getUsertype().startsWith("groupworker") | m.getUsertype().startsWith("payvehicle")) {
            if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("farmer")) {
                day_name.setText(m.getName());
                day_description.setText(m.getDescription());
                String locat = String.valueOf(databaseHandler.getfarmerlocation(m.getMobileno()));
                locat = locat.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "");
                Log.e("farmerlocation", locat);
                daybook_location.setText(locat);
                day_type.setText(m.getType());
                if (m.getName() != null && m.getName().startsWith("no")) {
                    day_name.setText(" ");
                } else if (m.getDescription() != null && m.getDescription().startsWith("no")) {
                    day_description.setText(" ");
                }

                day_amount.setText("\u20B9" + m.getExtraamt());
                if (m.getAmountout().startsWith("0.0") | m.getAmountout().startsWith("0")) {
               //     day_amount.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
                    Log.e("Amountout", m.getAmountout());
                    day_check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } else {
                //    day_amount.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.album_title));
                    Log.e("Amountout", m.getAmountout());
                    day_check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                day_time.setText(m.getCtime());
            } else {
                day_name.setText(m.getName());
                day_description.setText(m.getDescription());
                daybook_location.setText(m.getType());
                day_type.setText(m.getType());
                if (m.getName() != null && m.getName().startsWith("no")) {
                    day_name.setText(" ");
                } else if (m.getDescription() != null && m.getDescription().startsWith("no")) {
                    day_description.setText(" ");
                }

                day_amount.setText("\u20B9" + m.getExtraamt());
                if (m.getAmountout().startsWith("0.0") | m.getAmountout().startsWith("0")) {
                  //  day_amount.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
                    Log.e("Amountout", m.getAmountout());
                    day_check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } else {
                  //  day_amount.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.album_title));
                    Log.e("Amountout", m.getAmountout());
                    day_check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                day_time.setText(m.getCtime());
            }


        } else if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("advancefarmer") | m.getUsertype().startsWith("workeradvance") | m.getUsertype().startsWith("kgroupadvance") | m.getUsertype().startsWith("otherexpense") | m.getUsertype().startsWith("vehicle")) {
            if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("advancefarmer")) {
                day_name.setText(m.getName());
                day_description.setText(m.getDescription());
                day_type.setText(m.getType());
                String locat = String.valueOf(databaseHandler.getfarmerlocation(m.getMobileno()));
                locat = locat.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "");
                Log.e("farmerlocation", locat);
                daybook_location.setText(locat);
                if (m.getName() != null && m.getName().startsWith("no")) {
                    day_name.setText(" ");
                } else if (m.getDescription() != null && m.getDescription().startsWith("no")) {
                    day_description.setText(" ");
                }
                Log.e("amountout", m.getAmountout());
                day_amount.setText("\u20B9" + m.getAmountout());
                day_time.setText(m.getCtime());
            } else {
                day_name.setText(m.getName());
                day_description.setText(m.getType());
                day_type.setText(m.getType());
                daybook_location.setText(m.getDescription());
                if (m.getName() != null && m.getName().startsWith("no")) {
                    day_name.setText(" ");
                } else if (m.getDescription() != null && m.getDescription().startsWith("no")) {
                    day_description.setText(" ");
                }
                Log.e("amountout", m.getAmountout());
                day_amount.setText("\u20B9" + m.getAmountout());
                day_time.setText(m.getCtime());
            }


        } else if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("buyer")) {
            day_name.setText(m.getName());
            day_description.setText(m.getDescription());
            day_amount.setText("\u20B9" + m.getAmountin());
            day_type.setText(" ");
            day_time.setText(m.getCtime());
            daybook_location.setText(m.getType());
        }
        if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("farmer")) {
            day_usertype.setText("F");
            day_usertype.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_farmer);
        } else if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("advancefarmer")) {
            day_usertype.setText("FA");
            day_usertype.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_farmer);
        } else if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("singleworker")) {
            day_usertype.setText("W");
            day_usertype.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_worker);
        } else if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("workeradvance")) {
            day_usertype.setText("WA");
            day_usertype.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_worker);
        } else if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("groupworker")) {
            day_usertype.setText("G");
            day_usertype.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_worker);
        } else if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("kgroupadvance")) {
            day_usertype.setText("GA");
            day_usertype.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_worker);
        } else if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("otherexpense")) {
            day_usertype.setText("E");
            day_usertype.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_otherexpense);
        } else if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("vehicle")) {
            day_usertype.setText("V");
            day_usertype.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_vehicle);
        } else if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("gsalary")) {
            day_usertype.setText("GS");
            day_usertype.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_worker);
        } else if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("isalary")) {
            day_usertype.setText("WS");
            day_usertype.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_worker);
        } else if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("payvehicle")) {
            day_usertype.setText("VP");
            day_usertype.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_vehicle);
        } else if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("buyer")) {
            day_usertype.setText("B");
            day_usertype.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_buyer);
        }
    }
     convertview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
         @Override
         public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
             switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                 case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:


                     break;
                 case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                     if (!isListScrolling) {
                         view.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                         if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("farmer") | m.getUsertype().startsWith("advancefarmer")) {
                             String name = m.getName();
                             String mobno = m.getMobileno();
                             Intent a = new Intent(activity, FarmerLedgerView_Activity.class);
                             a.putExtra("farmername", name);
                             a.putExtra("farmermobno", mobno);
                             activity.startActivity(a);
                         } else if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("singleworker") | m.getUsertype().startsWith("workeradvance")) {
                             String name = m.getName();
                             String mobno = m.getMobileno();
                             Intent c = new Intent(activity, WorkerLedger_Activity.class);
                             c.putExtra("workername", name);
                             c.putExtra("workermobno", mobno);
                             activity.startActivity(c);
                         } else if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("groupworker") | m.getUsertype().startsWith("kgroupadvance")) {
                             String name = m.getName();
                             String mobno = m.getMobileno();
                             Intent g = new Intent(activity, GroupWorkerLedger_Activity.class);
                             g.putExtra("groupname", name);
                             g.putExtra("workermobno", mobno);
                             activity.startActivity(g);
                         } else if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("isalary")) {
                             String name = m.getName();
                             String mobno = m.getMobileno();
                             Intent d = new Intent(activity, Worker_paymenthistory_Activity.class);
                             d.putExtra("workername", name);
                             d.putExtra("workermobno", mobno);
                             activity.startActivity(d);
                         } else if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("bsalary")) {
                             Intent aa = new Intent(activity, WorkerListActivity.class);
                             activity.startActivity(aa);
                         } else if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("vehicle") | m.getUsertype().startsWith("payvehicle")) {
                             Intent s = new Intent(activity, VehicleList_activity.class);
                             activity.startActivity(s);
                         } else if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("otherexpense")) {
                             Intent b = new Intent(activity, OtherExpenseList.class);
                             activity.startActivity(b);
                         } else if (m.getUsertype().startsWith("buyer")) {
                             String name = m.getName();
                             String mobno = m.getMobileno();
                             Intent buyer = new Intent(activity, BuyerLedgerViewActivity.class);
                             buyer.putExtra("buyername", name);
                             buyer.putExtra("buyermobno", mobno);
                             activity.startActivity(buyer);

                         }
                     }

                     break;

             }


             return true;
         }
     });

    return convertview;
}
public void isScrolling(boolean isScroll) {
    isListScrolling = isScroll;
    Log.e("Innerscrollcheck", String.valueOf(isListScrolling));
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Getting ArrayIndexBounds Exception in BaseAdapter:

1: The reason is, activity is null. Check that you are instantiating the adapter, when you have a valid Context. E.g. inside onCreate. Since you are using the Activity only to retrieve the LayoutInflater you could also pass only the an instance of LayoutInflater

Try to do the following thing:

this.myInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
if you are in a fragment, this is the way to get the valid context

2:if u r using fragment then try this code

this.myInflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
public GridViewImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList filePaths) {}

use context instead of activity in ur code